# Jetson toolchain folder structure and libgomp linker error when cross-compiling

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, linker, nvidia-jetson

So I'm using NVIDIA's Jetson toolchain in a Docker container.

The toolchain seems to have a folder structure like this:

```
gcc-4.8.5-aarch64
    install
        aarch-unknown-linux-gnu
            bin
            include
            lib
            lib64
            sysroot
                etc
                lib
                sbin
                usr
                var
        bin
        include
        lib
        libexec
        share
```

There are nested directories with three lib dirs. I can compile my libraries e.g. `Boost` and `PCL` just fine but linking `PCL` to my application gives:

```
/install/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/../../../..
    /aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libgomp.so.1, needed by 
    /install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libpcl_common.so, not 
    found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libpcl_common.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_dynamic_next@GOMP_1.0'
```

The library *is* there:

```
./gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib64/libgomp.so.1
```

I have just extracted the toolchain tarball and set CMake SYSROOT to the enclosed `sysroot`. I'm still wondering if that's how it's supposed to by used. Should I, for example, move `libgomp.so.1` and other libraries from their current locations to the `sysroot` dir?

What is the correct way to make linker find `libgomp.so.1` here?

Comment: Having linker outside of sysroot (at `install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld`) looks suspicious. Have you tried to use `install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` as sysroot?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by moving `/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib64` under `/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/`. Not sure if that's 100% right, but everything now compiles and links beautifully.